# How to remove non-periodic lines from binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbeLZ.jpg)

I want to remove the lines (shown in RED color) as they are out of order. Lines shown in black color are repeating at same period (approximately). Period is not known beforehand. Is there any way of deleting non-periodic lines( shown in red color) automatically?

NOTE: Image is binary ( back & while).. lines shown in red color only for illustration.

Comment: Will there be fewer non-periodic lines than periodic ones?

Comment: @Balaji Average distance between lines by taking x coordinate( as I have coordinates of start and end point of every line).. but when non periodic lines are more( less likely)... average distance will not good indicator of period..                                                                           Mark - more likely they will be fewer

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is any way. There is almost always some way to do something.

Infortunately you have not provided any particular problem. The entire thing is too broad to be answered here.

To help you getting started: (I highly recommend you start with pen, paper and your brain)

Detect the lines -> google or think, there are many standard ways to detect lines in an image. if you don't have noise in your binary image its trivial.

find any aequidistant sets -> think
delete the rest -> think ( you know what is good so everything else has to go away)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your lines are (almost) vertical.

The following should work

- turn the image to a column sum histogram
- try a Fourier transformation on the signal (potentially padding the image appropriately)
- pick the maximum/peak from the Fourier spectrum as your base period

If you need the lines rather than the position of the lines, generate a mask with lines at appropriate intervals (as determined by your analysis before) and apply to the image.

Comment: No! not always vertical. They are actually detected hough lines and there is periodicity. but then we have some bad ones too ( which are mostly non-periodic).